# Something wrong with my jQuery carousel. [JSFiddle Link]

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm using this:
http://www.thomaslanciaux.pro/jquery/jquery_carousel.htm

Here's a link to the JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/svQpc/

It seems that only Vertical navigation works. When I use the Horizontal version, the image doesn't move, nothing switches.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @Sergio Boombastic: Are you using a `reset` stylesheet? How are your previous/next buttons styled and generated?

Comment: Fixed the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/svQpc/2/

Answer (score 1):

Works here:

http://jsfiddle.net/svQpc/1/

I did not change anything, just included the plug in, most likely you have a wrong path or some other code is interfering with the carousel.

Comment: Thanks for the help. While the jsfiddle link does work, in my project the images only move a little bit to the right. What would be causing this? The images don't scroll the length of their Width, just a little tiny bit to the left.

Comment: This could be caused by many reasons, can you post the rest of the code? maybe post a link?

Comment: Wow. Just tried it on Firefox and it works great. This must be an issue with just Google Chrome, right? What other plugin would you recommend that works the same on all most browsers?

Comment: I have used this one before: http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/examples/static_auto.html but there are several others you can try: http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/freebies/jquery-carousel-plugins-tutorials/